# Jmeter add Timestamp in wss

Tags: testing, soap, jmeter, wss

I need to put a test SOAP in Jmeter. This test is signed by Jmeter element "SOAP Message Signer".
I sign Timestamp, body and binary security token.
When i send test, this test send well but I'm not found timestamp element inside wssecurity tags like:

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-C5B52CA211571174C9151739434007851">
        <wsu:Created>2018-01-31T10:25:40.078Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2018-01-31T13:12:20.078Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
```

I need to put this element inside wss with Jmeter .
Anyone knows how can i do it?
Thnx.

Comment: Can you show How you configured your current test plan with Soap Message signer ? I don't quite understand your question, did you put the part you show in your message ?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to manually specify this header in the request body and use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to calculate current and future timestamps like:

```
<wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsu:Created>
        ${__groovy(use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { (new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") })}
    </wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>
        ${__groovy(use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { (new Date() + 3.hours).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") })}
    </wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

More information: [Running SOAP WS-Security Load Tests in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-soap-ws-security-load-tests-in-jmeter)

Comment: thanks, but i try to use SOAP message signer and this generate a Header signed. If take this header and put timestamp after 
it will not work beacause timestamp element is not signed. I need to put timestamp element and sign after to generate a valid header.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed the time stamp in UTC TimeZone hence had to change to

`<wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsu:Created>
        ${__groovy(use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
; (new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") })}
    </wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>
        ${__groovy(use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
;(new Date() + 3.hours).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") })}
    </wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>`

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about making the dates variables then you can use [__time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) functions this way:

```
 <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-C5B52CA211571174C9151739434007851">
    <wsu:Created>${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',)}</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,PT3H,,)}</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

Comment: thanks, but i try to use SOAP message signer and this generate a Header signed. If take this header and put timestamp after it will not work beacause timestamp element is not signed. I need to put timestamp element and sign after to generate a valid header